# Changing a value by JavaScript inside a ins tag

Tags: javascript, insert, variable-assignment, adsense

```
<ins class='adsbygoogle'
style='display:block'
data-ad-client='ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
data-ad-slot='000000000000'
data-ad-format='auto'
data-full-width-responsive='true'></ins>
```

I want to change `data-ad-slot` value to `123456789` with JavaScript. How can I do that?
I have tried this ~ (But not working)

```html
<ins class='adsbygoogle'
    style='display:block'
    data-ad-client='ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    data-ad-slot=document.write (x);
    data-ad-format='auto'
    data-full-width-responsive='true'></ins>

    <script> var x= 123456789;</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `.dataset.adSlot`.

```html
<ins class='adsbygoogle'
    style='display:block'
    data-ad-client='ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    data-ad-format='auto'
    data-full-width-responsive='true'></ins>
<script> 
var x= 123456789;
var elem = document.querySelector('.adsbygoogle');
elem.dataset.adSlot = x;
console.log(elem);
</script>
```

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1581; columnNumber: 18; Open quote is expected for attribute "data-ad-slot" associated with an element type "ins".

Comment: Thank you, you are amazing!

Comment: @MasudRana Glad to help.

Comment: Will it works in multiple places? or single change only? Can you tell me how to make it works in multiple places? I have that <ins> code multiple times on a page, and want to change all of them. :-)

Comment: You might want to ask a new question for that.